# Visual studio 2017 ASP.NET core MVC template application cannot add new packages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I installed Visual studio 2017 community edition and installed web development package to development asp.net web applications.

After installation, i created a new asp.net core MVC template application. This application runs without any compilation error.

However, it does not compile, if i add app.UseIdentity(); in the startup.cs.

I know i have to add an identity package to make it work.

I get "Package restore failed" message when i try to add "Microsoft identity" package from Package manager.

I have been struck with this issue for the past two days. Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

I have hosted my project in github
https://github.com/arjunprabu/WebApplication1

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to install the old Identity packages, there are new ones which belong to asp.net core.

An easy way to configure Identity to create a new project with Individual user accounts.

[image]

Comment: Tóth Tibor. This is a good fix for identity. But i cannot add any other packages to this application neither manually using package manager nor am i getting inteillisense help to add new package(i do not get this option http://imgur.com/a/iNHEF)